# "Part-Way" Freezing When Downloading large files

Tags: 15.10

[kmesg log/kern.log](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3naff5ifcj3kxjc/kern.log)

My problem I have come across was whenever I would download something more than ("I think") 150-200 megabytes my OS would freeze, but not my mouse. I could not click anything but every now and then the Num and Caps lock would blink rapidly when it would "part-way" freeze.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a problem with your browser. Try using something else, or use 'wget'. Also, look through the kmesg logs for possible issues related to the kernel.